# Cannot upgrade to 2.3.0 using Web Setup Wizard

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3, web-setup-wizard, php-7.2

I cannot upgrade using the admin System upgrade wizard. When I run the readiness checks everything passes apart from "Check Component Dependency".
The problem reads:

> " We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail Command
>   "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package
>   information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your
>   requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>   Problem 1
>   - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].
>   - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement. "

So I changed that in the server PHP manager the version to 7.1 and 7.2 and tried both. 7.2 just won't allow the site to work, 7.1 allows the site to work but still won't upgrade.

Can anyone please help, the server PHP from what I can tell is PHP Version 7.2.12.

Thank you.

Comment: You PHP version should be above 7.1.3. Try PHP version 7.1.24 tested and works fine.

Comment: This is what happens when i use 7.1.24 ??   heck Component Dependency

We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail

Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: several lines looking like this:

Comment: - magento/framework 100.1.15 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.24) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.0, 101.0.0].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.0, 101.0.1].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.0, 101.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.0, 101.0.3].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.0, 101.0.4].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/framework 102.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.0].

Comment: what is your current magento version?

Answer (score 0):

Update Magento version using command line because web setup wizard is not recommended as it may create such problem. Below is commands to update Magento version using command line.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 --no-update
composer update
```

Comment: Just tried that and got the following:

Comment: [~/public_html]# composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 --no-update

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 exists as magento/product-community-edition[2.2.7, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.1.0, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.1.1, 2.0.10, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.0.11, 2.1.4, 2.0.12, 2.1.5, 2.0.13, 2.1.6, 2.1.7, 2.0.14, 2.0.15, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.0.16, 2.2.0, 2.0.17, 2.2.1, 2.1.10] but these are rejected by your constraint.

Comment: Anyone Please help with this as solutions not working